# How to prompt for user input using a Matplotlib GUI rather than a command line prompt

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I to write a function `get_coords` which prompts the user for some input coordinates. One way to do this would be as follows:

```
def get_coords():
    coords_string = input("What are your coordinates? (x,y)")
    coords = tuple(coords_string)
    return coords
```

However, I'd like to use this using a GUI rather than the command line. I've tried the following:

```
def onclick(event):
    return (event.x, event.y)

def get_coords_from_figure():
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.axvline(x=0.5)      # Placeholder data
    plt.show(block=False)
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

However, using `coords = get_coords_from_figure()` results in a `coords` variable which is empty, unlike if I use `coords = get_coords()`, because the `input` function waits for user input.

How could I prompt a user for input using a GUI?

Comment: If you put a print inside onclick, will that print be printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_coords_from_figure():
    ev = None
    def onclick(event):
        nonlocal ev
        ev = event

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.axvline(x=0.5)      # Placeholder data
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

    plt.show(block=True)
    return (ev.xdata, ev.ydata) if ev is not None else None
    # return (ev.x, ev.y) if ev is not None else None
```

You need to actually return something your function (and block on the show).

If you need to have this function return, then define a class with `on_click` as a member method which mutates the objects state and then consult the object when you need to know the location.

Comment: The only thing is that the `nonlocal` keyword is only available in Python 3. How would I make this work in Python 2?