# Python threading on mac os crashes with the type of NSException

Tags: python, multithreading, macos, matplotlib

While trying to implement multithreading into my code, I have come across an error that appears to occur only on mac os. Here is the main part of the code, and when attempting to change the ox or oy variable from the thread, Python crashes. The goal of my code is to be able to run some code, such as adding obstacles for the dstar algorythm, while simultaneously graphing it with the matplotlib library.

```
"""

D* grid planning

author: Nirnay Roy

See Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D*)

"""
import math

from sys import maxsize

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import threading

show_animation = True


class State:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.parent = None
        self.state = "."
        self.t = "new"  # tag for state
        self.h = 0
        self.k = 0

    def cost(self, state):
        if self.state == "#" or state.state == "#":
            return maxsize

        return math.sqrt(math.pow((self.x - state.x), 2) +
                         math.pow((self.y - state.y), 2))

    def set_state(self, state):
        """
        .: new
        #: obstacle
        e: oparent of current state
        *: closed state
        s: current state
        """
        if state not in ["s", ".", "#", "e", "*"]:
            return
        self.state = state


class Map:

    def __init__(self, row, col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.map = self.init_map()

    def init_map(self):
        map_list = []
        for i in range(self.row):
            tmp = []
            for j in range(self.col):
                tmp.append(State(i, j))
            map_list.append(tmp)
        return map_list

    def get_neighbors(self, state):
        state_list = []
        for i in [-1, 0, 1]:
            for j in [-1, 0, 1]:
                if i == 0 and j == 0:
                    continue
                if state.x + i < 0 or state.x + i >= self.row:
                    continue
                if state.y + j < 0 or state.y + j >= self.col:
                    continue
                state_list.append(self.map[state.x + i][state.y + j])
        return state_list

    def set_obstacle(self, point_list):
        for x, y in point_list:
            if x < 0 or x >= self.row or y < 0 or y >= self.col:
                continue

            self.map[x][y].set_state("#")


class Dstar:
    def __init__(self, maps):
        self.map = maps
        self.open_list = set()

    def process_state(self):
        x = self.min_state()

        if x is None:
            return -1

        k_old = self.get_kmin()
        self.remove(x)

        if k_old < x.h:
            for y in self.map.get_neighbors(x):
                if y.h <= k_old and x.h > y.h + x.cost(y):
                    x.parent = y
                    x.h = y.h + x.cost(y)
        elif k_old == x.h:
            for y in self.map.get_neighbors(x):
                if y.t == "new" or y.parent == x and y.h != x.h + x.cost(y) \
                        or y.parent != x and y.h > x.h + x.cost(y):
                    y.parent = x
                    self.insert(y, x.h + x.cost(y))
        else:
            for y in self.map.get_neighbors(x):
                if y.t == "new" or y.parent == x and y.h != x.h + x.cost(y):
                    y.parent = x
                    self.insert(y, x.h + x.cost(y))
                else:
                    if y.parent != x and y.h > x.h + x.cost(y):
                        self.insert(y, x.h)
                    else:
                        if y.parent != x and x.h > y.h + x.cost(y) \
                                and y.t == "close" and y.h > k_old:
                            self.insert(y, y.h)
        return self.get_kmin()

    def min_state(self):
        if not self.open_list:
            return None
        min_state = min(self.open_list, key=lambda x: x.k)
        return min_state

    def get_kmin(self):
        if not self.open_list:
            return -1
        k_min = min([x.k for x in self.open_list])
        return k_min

    def insert(self, state, h_new):
        if state.t == "new":
            state.k = h_new
        elif state.t == "open":
            state.k = min(state.k, h_new)
        elif state.t == "close":
            state.k = min(state.h, h_new)
        state.h = h_new
        state.t = "open"
        self.open_list.add(state)

    def remove(self, state):
        if state.t == "open":
            state.t = "close"
        self.open_list.remove(state)

    def modify_cost(self, x):
        if x.t == "close":
            self.insert(x, x.parent.h + x.cost(x.parent))

    def run(self, start, end):

        rx = []
        ry = []

        self.insert(end, 0.0)

        while True:
            self.process_state()
            if start.t == "close":
                break

        start.set_state("s")
        s = start
        s = s.parent
        s.set_state("e")
        tmp = start

        while tmp != end:
            tmp.set_state("*")
            rx.append(tmp.x)
            ry.append(tmp.y)
            if show_animation:
                plt.plot(rx, ry, "-r")
            if tmp.parent.state == "#":
                self.modify(tmp)
                continue
            tmp = tmp.parent
        tmp.set_state("e")

        return rx, ry

    def modify(self, state):
        self.modify_cost(state)
        while True:
            k_min = self.process_state()
            if k_min >= state.h:
                break

m = Map(300, 300)
ox, oy = [], []
for i in range(0, 64):
    ox.append(i)
    oy.append(0)
for i in range(0, 32):
    ox.append(64)
    oy.append(i)
for i in range(0, 65):
    ox.append(i)
    oy.append(32)
for i in range(0, 32):
    ox.append(0)
    oy.append(i)


def add_obstacles():
    while True:
        a = [int(x) for x in input("x,y,xe,ye: ").split()]
        for i in range(a[1], a[3]):
            for j in range(a[0], a[2]):
                ox.append(j)
                oy.append(i)

def main():
    while True:
        start = [1, 16]
        goal = [63, 16]
        m.set_obstacle([(i, j) for i, j in zip(ox, oy)])
        if show_animation:
            plt.plot(ox, oy, ".k")
            plt.plot(start[0], start[1], "og")
            plt.plot(goal[0], goal[1], "xb")
            plt.axis("equal")
        
        start = m.map[start[0]][start[1]]
        end = m.map[goal[0]][goal[1]]
        dstar = Dstar(m)
        rx, ry = dstar.run(start, end)

        if show_animation:
            plt.plot(rx, ry, "-r")
            plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obstacle_thread = threading.Thread(target=add_obstacles)
    obstacle_thread.start()
    main()
```

Here is the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'nextEventMatchingMask should only be called from the Main Thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff811bed0b6 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff8116e2231 objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   AppKit                              0x00007ff815a71cc9 -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 4241
        3   _macosx.cpython-311-darwin.so       0x0000000102f0451c wait_for_stdin + 364
        4   Python                              0x000000010252c9d6 my_fgets + 40
        5   Python                              0x000000010252c8d6 PyOS_StdioReadline + 171
        6   Python                              0x000000010252cb13 PyOS_Readline + 167
        7   Python                              0x0000000102619e5a builtin_input_impl + 1491
        8   Python                              0x0000000102628363 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 50514
        9   Python                              0x000000010262b961 _PyEval_Vector + 92
        10  Python                              0x00000001026291ce _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 54205
        11  Python                              0x000000010262b961 _PyEval_Vector + 92
        12  Python                              0x0000000102551260 method_vectorcall + 426
        13  Python                              0x00000001026deefd thread_run + 163
        14  Python                              0x0000000102682983 pythread_wrapper + 36
        15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff811a9f202 _pthread_start + 99
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff811a9abab thread_start + 15
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I tried also putting matplotlib into the thread but that results nearly identical crash. So are there any solutioins as to how properly use the threads on mac os? Quick note, I am a beginner in Python coding, so that's probably a wrong way to do what I'm trying to, so any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Well, evidently you can't `input()` from another thread on macOS :) How about https://stackoverflow.com/a/38887795/51685 so you can click coordinates on the map instead of entering them?

Comment: Can you provide code that replicates this "issue"?

Comment: What is exactly is Map?

Comment: @CNGF a map is just a grid for the D* algorhythm that has all the obstacles mapped out. This is implemented using matplotlib.

Comment: @AKX input method is mostly for testing purposes, as I intend to expand the app by automatically adding the obstacles using the opencv library. I am stuck on how to later add the obstacles using the while true loop to run the code indefinitely while keeping the matplotlib code separate.

Comment: @CtrlZ I edited the post to include the full code. When the window opens, there is a prompt in a terminal requiring 4 number in the format of 1 2 3 4. After pressing enter, the code crashes.

Comment: @zhekch Right, so the stack trace says it's failing reading `input()`, so don't do that. If you make your other thread e.g. add random coordinates every 5 seconds, I'm pretty sure it doesn't crash.